# Server side lookup field filtering

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am developing my own lookup field.

I want it to have dynamically filtered values collection depends on user which makes new item.

What method of lookupfield class I should override to make my own collection of values to send on client to render there?

I need send from server to client side additional info about items in related lookup list as well.

And all this I really need to do on server side.

Multiple solutions all about client side... REST CSOM JSLINK CSR..

Any advice please about server.

Comment: From where you want to dynamically filter the values? And are you using custom authoring forms?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution with source code for your reference.

[sp2010filteredlookup](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sp2010filteredlookup)

[SharePoint 2013 Filtered Lookup Field](https://github.com/hasangok/sharepoint-2013-filtered-lookup-field)

[SharePoint 2016 Filtered Lookup Field](https://github.com/hasangok/sharepoint-2016-filtered-lookup-field)